# a work around for pulling data into R considering mini options contracts

Tags: r, quantmod

I have been pulling options chains in with a function in quantmod called `getOptionsChain`. Now that there are mini options contracts offered on stocks like GOOG, AAPL, etc., it throws a bug into my code.  I'm striping out the numbers after the symbol and now the mini contracts are threaded through all the data with a GOOG7. Any ideas?

```
library(quantmod)
underlying <- 'GOOG'
# set what your volatility forcast or assumption is
volforcast <- .25
# Get symbols current price
yqf <- "Last Trade (Price Only)"
underlying.price <- getQuote(underlying,what=yahooQF(yqf))$Last

OC <- getOptionChain(underlying, NULL)
#check data
head(OC)
lputs <- lapply(OC, FUN = function(x) x$puts)
head(lputs) #check for NA values, yahoo returns all NA values sometimes
puts <- do.call('rbind', lputs )
#check data
head(puts,150)

symbols <- as.vector(unlist(lapply(lputs, rownames)))
expiries <- unlist(lapply(symbols, function(x) {
  regmatches(x=x, regexpr('[0-9]{6}', x)) } ))
puts$maturity <- as.numeric((as.Date(expiries, "%y%m%d") - Sys.Date())/365)
GetIV <- function(type, value,
              underlying, strike,dividendYield, riskFreeRate, maturity, volatility,
              timeSteps=150, gridPoints=151) {


  AmericanOptionImpliedVolatility(type, value,
                                  underlying, strike,dividendYield, riskFreeRate, maturity,  volatility, timeSteps=150, gridPoints=151)$impliedVol
}
#this is the part that throws the error due to NA values in puts$maturity
puts$IV <- mapply(GetIV, value = puts$Ask, strike = puts$Strike, maturity = puts$maturity,
                  MoreArgs= list(type='put', underlying= underlying.price,
                  dividendYield=0, riskFreeRate = 0.01,  
                  volatility = volforcast), SIMPLIFY=TRUE)
#this is the error Error: Date's serial number (-2147442285) outside allowed range [367-109574],      i.e. [January 1st, 1901-December 31st, 2199]
```

I want to avoid adding the rows where `puts$maturity` is `NA`.

Comment: you should at least show us what the bug is. Error message? Wrong answer? Computer catches fire?

Comment: Since you know the year and month of expiry
from `names(OC)`,
you can change the regular expression 
`[0-9]{6}`, which is too general, to something more precise, such as `1304[0-9]{2}`.

Comment: 1304 first?  if you tail(puts,10)  you will see GOOG150117P01260000  which is is jan 17 2015 expiration.. i don't get the reg expression you put up .. but i think your assuming 1304 to be constant.. thats the year and day..  its this GOOG7130420P00780000  with the GOOG7 representing the mini contracts with GOOG7 that throws the Na's

Answer (score 1):

You only want rows where `puts$maturity` is not `NA`?  This would accomplish that goal:

```
puts <- puts[!is.na(puts$maturity), ]
```

The other option, as [@VincentZoonekynd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1129973/vincent-zoonekynd) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15715509/a-work-around-for-pulling-data-into-r-considering-mini-options-contracts#comment22326474_15715509) is to use a better regular expression.

For example, this looks for symbols that begin with capital letters, followed by 6 digits followed by either a "C" or a "P" followed by 8 digits and nothing else.  It will not pick up symbols that have 7 digits after the ticker.

```
symbols <- c("GOOG7130420P00695000", "GOOG130426P00720000")
grep("^[A-Z]+\\d{6}[CP]\\d{8}$", symbols, value=TRUE)
#[1] "GOOG130426P00720000"
```

`^[A-Z]+`: begins with (`^`) any capital letter (`[A-Z]`), one or more times (`+`)
`\\d{6}` : followed by 6 (`{6}`) digits (`\\d`)
`[CP]`   : followed by either the letter "C" or "P"
`\\d{8}$`: ending with 8 (`{8}`) digits (`\\d`) with nothing after them (`$`)

---

Per the wishes in the comments, here is one way to remove the rows you don't want before doing anything else.  It just recreates the object with only the stuff you care about.

```
OC <- lapply(OC, function(x) {
  list(calls=x$calls[grep("[A-Z]\\d{6}[CP]\\d{8}$", rownames(x$calls)), ],  
       puts=x$puts[grep("[A-Z]\\d{6}[CP]\\d{8}$", rownames(x$puts)), ],
       symbol=x$symbol)
})
```

Comment: while this is good.. there are other dependencies in the code that cause it to break still .. ideally the list 'OC' needs to have the GOOG7's subsetted out..

Comment: Sorry @cdcaveman, I thought that was clear.  Try this `lputs <- lapply(OC, FUN = function(x) x$puts[grep("[A-Z]\\d{6}[CP]\\d{8}$", rownames(x$puts)), ])`.  If that doesn't work I'll work through your code and update the answer.

Comment: i really think its best to subset out the data in the 'OC' variable right off the bat.. its a list of lists.. i'm not sure how to do that.. i'm sure i could apply that grep as an argument to some function that returns the amended lists

Comment: interesting.. i got it working with     `lputs <- lapply(OC, FUN = function(x) x$puts[grep("[A-Z]\\d{6}[CP]\\d{8}$", rownames(x$puts)), ])`

Answer (score 1):

For a succinct filter that removes 'GOOG7' or any underlying security symbol followed by '7', try the following:

```
symbols <- grep(paste("^",underlying,"[0-6,8-9]", sep="", collapse = NULL), 
                symbols, value = TRUE)
```

Comment: Could also look for "GOOG7" and `invert` to only keep the ones that are not "GOOG7": `grep(paste("^", underlying, "7", sep=""), symbols, value=TRUE, invert=TRUE)`.  This code should work until options expiring in the year 2070 are listed.

Comment: Another way to get everything that does not have a 7 after the ticker: `grep(paste("^",underlying,"[^7]", sep=""), symbols, value = TRUE)`.  Inside brackets(`[]`), the `^` means "not"